# Ok to have Entity Framework and Entity Framework Core in the same project or is this a smell?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Environment: Visual Studio 2019

I've already got EF Core installed in my C# project, but I need the following from EF6 to work as well.

```
return Context.Database.SqlQuery<T>($"EXEC {spName}").ToList();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a smell, but given the limitations of EfCore - it is an acceptable smell until they fix the most glaring issues in EfCore (which seems to happen now for the 5.0 release timeframe).

Answer (score 3):

The equivilent in EF Core is FromSql/[FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-3.1) which are extension methods on `DbSet<TEntity>`, eg

```
return context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw($"EXEC {spName}").ToList();
```

In combination with registering the type as an [Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) or a [Keyless Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations).

Comment: Ahh, this works for me but I already checked the answer. I don't know the etiquette here, sorry.

Comment: It's fine to have multiple answers, and doesn't matter much which one is accepted.